# After converting MySQL key columns to a FOREIGN Columns the site slowed down

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I never used FOREIGN KEYS before. I always placed the id it a key column but it is not necessary a foreign key. so it acts like a foreign key but it is not.

so if I have the following 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
 `account_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
 `owner_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`account_id`),
 KEY `owner_id` (`owner_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(60) NOT NULL
 PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

the column account.owner_id is linked to users.user_id but without setting a foreign key relationship.

so I can do something like this

```
SELECT
a.name AS account_name,
u.name AS user_name FROM
accounts AS a INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.user_id = a.owner_id
```

So after learning what FOREIGN KEYS are and what they do I have created a foreign key like so.

```
ALTER TABLE accounts 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_owner_id FOREIGN KEY(owner_id)
REFERENCES users(user_id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

However, I notices a performance change as they system slowed down a lot. I am not sure if adding FOREIGN KEYs will reuse performance or no? or is there a performance reduction when adding a foreign keys to a table?
Please note that that there are lots of tables and columns in my database. so I do many INNER/LEFT/RIGHT JOINS and all the columns where i identified them as FOREIGN KEYS are indexed. Notices that I did not add any indexes to this columns as all of they already exists prior adding the FOREIGN keys to my database.

my question, will FOREIGN KEYs reduce performance on UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE/SELECT?
Also is there a benefit of adding a FOREIGN KEY constraint when we specified ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION?

Thanks

Comment: On the outset, everything you have done looks correct and no there should not have been a performance hit. Are you certain the slowdown is attributed to the query you provided? Try running the same query with an `EXPLAIN` before it, see if the optimizer provides any insight.

Comment: I am not sure it feels that the whole site slowed down and not a pacific query. it raised a flag when i see the system is slow. So i was not sure if it is a FOREIGN KEYS issue or not. so do you suggest the use of FKs or no?

Comment: Ya, use FKs whenever possible. Mitigating this responsibility to the database layer will make your app lighter (code wise) and ensure you don't end up with orphaned rows in the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The foreign key constraint means that any insert to the FK column has to check if the value exists in the referenced column of users.  There could be some overhead to this, but it's an index lookup by definition (probably a PK lookup) so the cost shouldn't be high.

Foreign keys also create a shared lock on the parent table during some updates on the child table.  This can get in the way of concurrent updates against that table, and make it seem like the system has slower performance.  See http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/12/12/innodb-locking-and-foreign-keys/

The foreign key also implicitly created an index on the FK column, if no index already exists.  Every insert, update, delete has to modify all the indexes of a table at the time of the change, so there is a bit of overhead.  For this reason, some people say indexes "hurt" performance of insert, update, delete.  But it's not that simple -- an index that *supports* conditions in a WHERE clause can make an update or delete run faster by finding the affected rows more efficiently.

---

Re your comment:

Yes, any update to the child tables creates an **exclusive lock** on the modified row in the child table.  You probably expected this.  But this action also creates a **shared lock** on the referenced row in `clients`.  Any number of sessions may independently create shared locks on the same row (hence the name shared).  But an exclusive lock requires that there be no lock of any type.  So if there are frequently shared locks outstanding on a row in `clients`, then direct updates to that row in `clients` can't get the required exclusive lock.

The purpose of these shared locks is basically so that the row in `clients` doesn't get removed or modified while someone is updating a row that depends on it.  In other words, "don't delete my parent."  But depending on the frequency of updates and the duration of transactions, it could make it hard to perform updates to a parent row.

One way to mitigate this is to try to make locks live for shorter periods of time, by finishing the work for a transactions promptly, and then commit.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer, so if I have client table and I have 10 other tables linked to it using FKs. Every time an update is made to one of those 10 tables a lock is made of the clients table? if one of those tables is used is most of my queries then for sure the constant locks placed on the clients table will be locked most of the time. please help me understand this. Thanks